# Sonarqube.com login with github issue: mail is already used by an existing user

Tags: github, sonarqube

I got the following error when login into sonarqube.com:

```
You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator.
Reason : You can't sign up because email 'abc@abc.com' is already used by an existing user. This means that you probably already registered with another account.
```

It seems the issue is that the github handle of the above account got changed as some point!

Comment: As suggested by the error, have you tried to contact the administrator of sonarqube.com ?

Comment: I looked around for the administrator contact information and the "Get support" page suggested to ask on Stack Overflow. So, where do I find the contact information?

Comment: Here : https://about.sonarqube.com/contact/

Comment: Thanks! That was really hidden as the "about" link at the bottom of the page gets you to https://sonarqube.com/about.

Comment: Ok, I'm adding an answer for other people that may ask themself the same question

Answer (score 0):

Please use [about.sonarqube.com/contact](http://about.sonarqube.com/contact) in order to contact administrator of sonarqube.com